# python: what does the colon mean?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read the code [simpy](https://gitlab.com/team-simpy/simpy/-/blob/master/src/simpy/core.py), but i have some questions.

```
def __init__(self, initial_time: SimTime = 0):
    self._now = initial_time
    self._queue: List[
        Tuple[SimTime, EventPriority, int, Event]
    ] = []  # The list of all currently scheduled events.
    self._eid = count()  # Counter for event IDs
    self._active_proc: Optional[Process] = None

    # Bind all BoundClass instances to "self" to improve performance.
    BoundClass.bind_early(self)
```

what does the colon mean?
`initial_time: SimTime = 0`

```
  self._queue: List[Tuple[SimTime, EventPriority, int, Event]] = []
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: It is type declaration, the ```:``` is used as a separator to denote the type of the particular variable that you have created or referred. This is a new feature in python, in a idea to make it a strongly typed language, before it was a dynamically typed -> weakly typed, this is a new feature, Kindly refer the release notes it has everything mentioned. If you are new, maybe you can take it a resemblance to Typescript or just note that that denotes what variable types should be out in there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not too familiar with the rules of the forum. So I'm not quite sure if I should reply "thank you" below your answer。

Comment: Replying is totally fine. Also, try checking out answers and accepting them, as they are spending time answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a Typedef Hint for a defined variable, with a special type of `SimTime` with value 0 being passed into the function.

If you get a chance, check out PEP483, PEP484, as well as the `typing` module for more information on Typedef hints.

Since it seems to be an uncommon type, I would check for Type Aliases as well. PEP613 is about Type Aliases.

I don't know what else it could be, but maybe it is something else.